# Consuming WSDL containing long named fields with PeopleSoft

Tags: peoplesoft

I'm exposing WSDLs to PeopleSoft client. On one WSDL, with particularity long field name, the PeopleSoft Integration broker auto-generates SOAP message with trimmed field name (only the first 30 characters appear).

This message failed, of course.

I was looking at Oracle PeopleSoft documentation (Home > PeopleBooks > PeopleTools 8.52: PeopleSoft Integration Broker > Consuming Services) but I couldn't find this constraint, nor a solution.

I found this constraint on another part of the documentation  (Home > PeopleBooks > PeopleTools 8.52: PeopleSoft Integration Broker > Managing Messages), but this part is about creating your own message parts, so no workaround is present.

Is it possible that PeopleSoft can't work with a perfectly valid WSDL?

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm not a PeopleSoft developer. It's just that the developers here lack the ability to make a research, so I'm doing it instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write Transform program(s) and add them on to the routing for the service operation.  This way you could transform the name of the field from the actual name to the PeopleSoft abbreviation as required.  The transformations can be written in PeopleCode or XSLT

[Developing Transform Programs Using PeopleSoft Application Engine](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41633_01/pt853pbh1/eng/pt/tibr/task_DevelopingTransformProgramsUsingPeopleSoftApplicationEngine-0762f0.html)

Comment: Alas, the poor bums at my place are too lazy for developing new skills. I was forced to change my WSDL... I guess that your answer is correct, but I'll never know.